# What « Super User » mean in the StackEchange network?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I recently browsed into the [Stack Exhange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) page and saw a Community called « Super User » and even after looking for a definition online I found the following:

> a consumer of electrical power.

Which does not make that much sense to me (considering that I am a non-native english speaker), so I logged in into https://superuser.com/ and did the "presentation tour" in order to understand it better, but even after that it's far from being clear to me

You'll be able to find more details below:

> Super User
>   Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users

[image: superuser]

Does anyone could please help me to understand it better and what does it precisely mean ?

**Edit:** To make it more clear, how can you make a difference between a normal user and a super user on a computer?

Comment: Are you asking for the meaning of "SuperUser", or of the phrase "consumer of electrical power"?  If the former, why not ask on SuperUser, or on their Meta site?  If the latter, please rephrase your question (and show your research -- use a dictionary).

Comment: Yes I'm asking for the meaning of "SuperUser" sorry if it was unclear

Comment: Think of the class of computer users as a spectrum, starting from those who only do email, web, and social media (and maybe solitaire), to those who add office productivity like Word and Excel, to those who have more sophisticated software for specialist needs, like Engineers.  Continue up to die-hard on-line gamers, those who write code for a living, up to those who dig into the internals, write custom batch files and scripts, modify their registries, and virtually perform surgery on their machines.  The upper end of that spectrum are colloquially called Super Users.

Comment: Well, visit their [help page](https://superuser.com/help).

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you for this useful link, however it does not help me to understand the meaning of "SuperUser", for instance whan using a computer, how can you make the difference between a normal user and a super user ?

Comment: A "superuser" is a computer nerd.  It's really just a joke, though, since the site is basically just the catch-all for computer questions that don't suit another site.

Comment: What search engine told you it is a "consumer of electrical power"?  Google gives me as its definition "a user of a computer system with special privileges needed to administer and maintain the system; a system administrator."

Comment: Perhaps "power user" was confusing.  A "power user" is a user (presumably of computers) who is relatively skilled and somewhat obsessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A super user is the one having admin authority. i.e. He can control the work flow and working of the project or task.
A normal user on other hand has limited authority. that means he/she can only perform the task predefined in the manner of the super user